# Moving Document Sets with more than 12 look up to a record center

Tags: document-archiving

I have a library with "Information Management Policy" enabled in it, library contains **22 User Group** columns, **4 managed metadata** columns and few other columns.

But when the expiration policy is executed , items in the library are not moved to the drop off library of the record center site.

It seems we can have only **12 lookup columns** as recommended by Microsoft in the source library.

Is it good to increase the **List view lookup threshold** at the web application level ? Or is there any other better approach that can resolve this issue ?

Thanks.